# Is a noun used for multiple adjectives singular or plural?

Tags: grammar, idiomatic-language

An example is probably easiest.

In the context of programming, we are talking about a value which has two fields, a field pointing to a previous value and a field pointing to a next value.

Are all formulations below correct?

- > Where each value has an optional previous and next field.
- > Where each value has optional previous and next fields.
- > Where each value has an optional previous field and an optional next field.

The first two here attempt to "group" things together, for brevity, however it's unclear to me whether then `field` should be singular or plural:

- Singular sounds weird, since there's 2 fields.
- Plural still sounds iffy, due to the fact there is a single of each.

Bonus question: is there a better, brief, formulation?

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence indicates that each value has only one field (which is described as "previous and next"); that is incorrect, according to what you wrote.

The second sentence is correct but a bit vague; we don't know how many "previous and next fields" each value has.

The last sentence is also correct but less vague, so it is probably the best. However, there are shorter formulations, e.g.:

> . . . where each value has two optional fields: "previous" and "next".

Answer (score 0):

The first sentence sounds like there is one field: a "previous and next" field.

Your second sentence is the one I would use and is the most correct. The value has two optional fields: a previous field and a next field, and therefore you should use plural *fields*.

I assume the third sentence is supposed to be "an optional previous field and an optional next field." This is correct, but unnecessarily repetitive, and as a result it is more difficult to understand.

**In short**: use the second version.

Comment: Hi Esther, I edited the post's third example sentence so it now reads as you suggest.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan: Thanks for that, I accidentally missed a word :(

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the technical vocabulary of programming, but, in normal English and mathematics, “value” indicates something singular, a number.

In mathematics, we would talk about an ordered pair of numbers, one being the preceding address of X and the other being the succeeding address of X.

Not knowing the technical vocabulary of your intended audience, I do not whether my suggestion is helpful.